# Raid 1/10: Kernel panic- not syncing: attempted to kill init

Tags: linux, centos, raid, partition, software-raid

I have setup Raid 1 & Raid 10 in Virtual Box for learning purpose.

The following Partitions for 4 Hard Drives:

I make a 100mb partition (/boot) on four drives and make that a raid 1 partition.

Then with the remaining space on each drive, I've setup software raid 10 and configure it to LVM.  In the LVM I setup a 4gb swap partition and 20GB for root partition (/) as ext4.

It appear to be working when I have installed CentOS 6.2 64Bit. Then I decided to remove second HD (Disk2.vdi) to see what happen and restart the virtual machine then I get an error:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

This is where I get stuck. I was expecting OS to load up fine and let me know one disk has failed, but it didn't. What's wrong?

Edit: I dug further to see what went wrong, here's the screenshot:

[image]

Is this normal when a disk fails? Or did I not setup the partitions/raid correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got it to work! Many thanks to 'Shane Madden' for help and advice in 'The Comms Room' Chat.

There is a bug in CentOS - http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5400

To solve this problem:

- Reinstall CentOS again and create Partitions (Raid 1 & Raid 10)
- Once installed, you must `yum update` to update the system
- Restart the server
- Take out any disk and restart .. it should load to OS fine without kernel error :)

Why didn't it let me know there was a disk failure?

Comment: Well, it kinda did up at the top with the missing LVM Groups. Upvote for you for sticking with this one. These problems are always excellent learning experiences.